# Notepad++ Regex to find multiple words in a document?

Tags: regex, search, notepad++

I am looking for the following words in my document:

```
"substr" 
"500"
"description"
```

I am using the following expression to try and match this:

```
(substr|500|description)
```

That works to find any of these words, but I want to jump to lines that only contain ALL of these words. Is there any way to do this? I don't want an OR condition, I want to AND on all of these words.

So for example:

```
test substr line one
test substr, 500 line two
test substr, 500, description line three <<--- only go to this line when I hit next!!
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you looking for the words to occur in the same order?

Comment: No, order doesn't necessarily matter, but the words do appear in a regular pattern on each line. Regardless, I only want to go to a line that contains all of these words in any particular order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To match them in any order you can use *positive lookaheads* `?=`:

```
((?=.*\bsubstr\b)(?=.*\b500\b)(?=.*\bdescription\b).*)
```

To match them in the given order is much easier:

```
.*substr.*500.*description.*
```